# Cleanup a function with parameters inside a loop of event listener (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, removeeventlistener

I don't really know what is going on, but I think that the removeEventListener is not working properly.
Here is my code, my app is crashing everytime I click more than 5 times on any of the buttons and I can't find a solution anywhere.

```
const doTri = (e) => {
    if(e.id === "active"){
      setOrder(!order);
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("active")?.removeAttribute("id");
      e.setAttribute('id', 'active');
      setTri(e.classList[1]);
      setOrder(true)
    }
  }

useEffect(() => {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("headerBtn")).forEach((e)=>{
      e.addEventListener('click', ()=>{doTri(e)})
    })
  
    return () => {
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("headerBtn")).forEach((e)=>{
        e.removeEventListener('click',()=>{doTri(e)})
      })
    }
  }, [tri,order])
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `getElementsByClassName` in React really.

Comment: what should I use instead ?

Comment: Render elements as intended with jsx. Example from official docs: https://github.com/ahfarmer/calculator/blob/master/src/component/ButtonPanel.js

Comment: what if I have alot of elements ?

Comment: Render a list https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I said the removeEventListener function wasn't working so I did some changes in order to not pass any params to the do tri functions, that is what I did and it worked.

```
const doTri = (e) => {
    if(e.currentTarget.id === "active"){
      setOrder(!order);
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("active")?.removeAttribute("id");
      e.currentTarget.setAttribute('id', 'active');
      setTri(e.currentTarget.classList[1]);
      setOrder(true)
    }
  }

useEffect(() => {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("headerBtn")).forEach((e)=>{
      e.addEventListener('click', doTri)
    })
  
    return () => {
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("headerBtn")).forEach((e)=>{
        e.removeEventListener('click', doTri)
      })
    }
  }, [tri,order])
```